# How String Theory calculates the Entropy of the Black Hole in a Background dependent way?

Tags: black-hole, general-relativity, quantum-mechanics, entropy

How does string theory get an agreement to the Hawking-Bekenstein equations to calculate the quantum entropy of a black hole in a background dependent way?

Is there any sort of area parameter in string theory like Barbero-Immirzi in loop quantum gravity?

Comment: I'm reopening this. Theoretical astrophysical thermodynamics questions are on topic here: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/450/6

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @antispinwards The user has already stated that they are no longer able to ask questions on Physics.